# Display one quiz per page using ejs nodes and mongo db to create a quiz

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, ejs

I have used ejs in code in my html/ejs code and have used 'ForEach'that display all the quizzes in the database successfully but need to know how to manipulate the buttons in JavaScript, to display on submit the next question
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ld55o.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RtPB.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Provide some code so I could understand the problem

Comment: I have provided two images above I would like to know how to get user choice the actual value of the radio button and match it to the answer to increment it to their score. choice value current display 'on'.